# google maps get street number in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, geolocation

how to get street number from google map in swift?

my code:

```
let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()

geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(place.coordinate) { response, error in

   if let address = response?.firstResult() {
      print(address)
   }
})
```

and i get this:

```
GMSAddress {
coordinate: (56.966157, 24.054405)
lines: Buļļu iela 21, Kurzeme District, Rīga, LV-1055, Latvia
thoroughfare: 21 Buļļu iela
locality: Rīga
administrativeArea: Rīgas pilsēta
postalCode: LV-1055
country: Latvia
}
```

So... how to get street number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thoroughfare` returns the street and street number. Check the [GMSAddress](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_address) documentation.

If you want to get the street number from the `thoroughfare` result `string`, you can the method below.

```
func getStreetNumber(street : String){
     let str = street
     let streetNumber = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
     NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
     print(streetNumber)
}
```

**UPDATE**

**To get the number only**

I have called `getStreetNumber("531 W 217th St, New York")` and the method below prints out **531**.

```
var number = ""
var hasValue = false

// Loops thorugh the street
for i in street.characters {
    let str = String(i)
    // Checks if the char is a number
    if (Int(str) != nil){
        // If it is it appends it to number
        number+=str
       // Here we set the hasValue to true, beacause the street number will come in one order
       // 531 in this case
       hasValue = true
    }
    else{
        // Lets say that we have runned through 531 and are at the blank char now, that means we have looped through the street number and can end the for iteration
        if(hasValue){
            break
        }
   }
}
print(number)
```

**To get the address only**

```
func getStreetNumber(street : String){
        let str = street
        let streetNumber = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
            NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
        print(streetNumber)

        var address = street
        var hasValue = false

        // Loops thorugh the street
        for i in street.characters {
            let str = String(i)
            // Checks if the char is a number
            if (Int(str) != nil){
                // If it is it appends it to number
                address = address.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(str, withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                // Here we set the hasValue to true, beacause the street number will come in one order
                // 531 in this case
                hasValue = true
            }
            else{
                // Lets say that we have runned through 531 and are at the blank char now, that means we have looped through the street number and can end the for iteration
                if(hasValue){
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        print(address)
    }
```

Comment: yes, but if my  address is: "531 W 217th St, New York" i get: 531217

Comment: @user3546854, I have added a new method that will check for the first consecutive numbers in a string. Try it out.

Comment: Nice! it  works, maybe you can help how to get address? without street number?

Comment: I have updated the code to get the address too. @user3546854

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression you can get both the street number and street from the `thoroughfare` in one go. This makes your address parsing code much more flexible because you will only have to make minimal changes in the *splitStreetNumber(in:)* method if you decide to tweak it later. Also the *substrings* method is extremely reusable.

```
extension NSRegularExpression {

    func substrings(in string: String, options: MatchingOptions = [], range rangeOrNil: NSRange? = nil) -> [[String?]] {

        // search the full range of the string by default
        let range = rangeOrNil ?? NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count)
        let matches = self.matches(in: string, options: options, range: range)

        // parse each match's ranges into strings
        return matches.map{ match -> [String?] in

            return (0..<match.numberOfRanges)
                // map each index to a range
                .map{ match.range(at: $0) }
                // map each range to a substring of the given string if the range is valid
                .map{ matchRange -> String? in
                    if let validRange = range.intersection(matchRange) {
                        return (string as NSString).substring(with: validRange)
                    }
                    return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

func splitStreetNumber(in streetAddress: String) -> (streetNumber: String?, street: String?) {

    // regex matches digits at the beginning and any text after without capturing any extra spaces
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^ *(\\d+)? *(.*?) *$", options: .caseInsensitive)

    // because the regex is anchored to the beginning and end of the string there will
    // only ever be one match unless the string does not match the regex at all
    if let strings = regex.substrings(in: streetAddress).first, strings.count > 2 {
        return (strings[1], strings[2])
    }
    return (nil, nil)
}
```

Result

```
'  1234 Address Dr  ' -> ('1234', 'Address Dr')
'1234 Address Dr'     -> ('1234', 'Address Dr')
'Address Dr'          -> (nil, 'Address Dr')
'1234'                -> ('1234', nil)
```

Comment: the code above will never return `(nil, 'Address Dr')` as I see

Comment: The first capture group in the regular expression is `(\\d+)?` which means it optionally captures a group of consecutive digits. Drop the code in a playground and call `splitStreeNumber(in: "Address Dr")`. The output will be `(nil, "Address Dr")`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
func splitStreetNumber(in streetAddress: String) -> (streetNumber: String?, street: String?) {
    let words = streetAddress.split(separator: " ")
    var lastIndex: Int?
    for (index, word) in words.enumerated() where word.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) != nil {
        lastIndex = index
    }
    guard let lindex = lastIndex else { return (nil, streetAddress) }
    var nChars: [String] = []
    var sChars: [String] = []
    for (index, word) in words.enumerated() {
        if index <= lindex {
            nChars.append(String(word))
        } else {
            sChars.append(String(word))
        }
    }
    let number = nChars.joined(separator: " ")
    let street = sChars.joined(separator: " ")
    return (number.isEmpty ? nil : number, street.isEmpty ? nil : street)
}
```